# How to run update-initramfs from bootable usb?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, kernel-panic

My computer froze during an upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

This resulted in a kernel panic upon reboot.

```
/sbin/init: relocation error: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: symbol__clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference.
```

[followed by some kernel panic stuff]

I booted from usb and finished the upgrade via by chroot into the drive and running: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` 
(as well as a few other commands as described in: [Recover from shutdown during Ubuntu distribution upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/8540))

Basically it appears to have finished the upgrade, but it did not produce a new boot image: `update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media`

Since I cannot boot into older kernel versions, is there a way to produce a new boot image (i.e. something that would be in /boot/) from the usb.

As further clarification, when chrooted, `uname -a` yields the updated kernel, but no corresponding kernel image is in the /boot of the drive.

Could use some advice.

Comment: As a followup, I decided to simply re-install as I could not get this working.  Would still be curious to hear a solution if anyone has one, and perhaps it would help others...

Answer (score 4):

I had a [similar issue involving](https://askubuntu.com/a/696653/40581) the `update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media` error message. If you look at the script you can see that it is just a wrapper script to `mkinitramfs`.

```
whereis update-initramfs
update-initramfs: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs …
gedit /usr/sbin/update-initramfs
```

So you could call `mkinitramfs` directly:

```
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-${kernel_ver}-generic ${kernel_ver}-generic
```

More details about reinstalling kernel and initrd images from live media/chroot in the link above.

Answer (score 3):

You mention `chroot`ing into new ubuntu install. Run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

all **FROM INSIDE** the chroot

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  At the time of my original post, I had tried running "sudo update-initramfs" from inside the chroot.  When within "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade", it uses initramfs, it gave an error and if I tried directly using "sudo update-initramfs", the same error came up then as while it was running.

Comment: still having issues or did you get it sorted out?  If not, try adding  mount --bind /run  /sys   /mntpt/{dev,sys}

Comment: I did a fresh install, so I didn't really answer my original question.  I played around with "--bind" when I mounted, but I still had trouble running update-initramfs even when I mounted that way and was in chroot.  Perhaps, if done correctly, that would have worked?

Comment: feel free to reference my write up which shows way to do it  (substitute drive / mount points as suits your needs...   for this particular question lines 89-91 are showing mount --bind properly done. https://gist.github.com/linux-modder/55e49074ff947ca0f97c

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865626/luks-cryptosetup-and-lvm-cant-input-passwords-after-boot/865783#865783

Answer (score 0):

on Linux Mint's live cd, there is a copy of update-initramfs that is used for installation.  It is renamed "update-initramfs.distrib".  You can run this to recreate your initrd.